# Erro ao tentar conectar smack ao openfire

Tags: java, openfire

Estou tentando realizar um exemplo simples para conectar em um servidor openfire, utilizando a biblioteca smack 4.0.6 e tenho o seguinte código:

```
ConnectionConfiguration configuration= new ConnectionConfiguration(ADDRESS, 5222);
configuration.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
SSLContext sc = null;
try {
    sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new AcceptAllTrustManager() }, new SecureRandom());
} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
configuration.setCustomSSLContext(sc);
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configuration);
try {
   connection.connect();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return;
}
```

A parte do protocolo TSL ele consegue realizar completamente, no entanto, quando tento conectar ele retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jivesoftware/smackx/disco/ServiceDiscoveryManager
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.hoxt.HOXTManager$1.connectionCreated(HOXTManager.java:43)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.initConnection(XMPPTCPConnection.java:490)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:440)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:811)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:396)
at Main.main(Main.java:56)
```

O que me leva a crer que o que falta é uma biblioteca que tenha a definição da classe `ServiceDiscoveryManager`. Entretanto já importei todas as bibliotecas que é [fornecida pela Ignite](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) e ainda sim não funciona.

Qual a dependência que está faltando para ele?

Comment: Felipe, como está fazendo build da sua aplicação? É aplicação Web? Usa alguma ferramenta que gerencia as dependências ou está baixando os `jars` e colocando na pasta `libs`?

Comment: Estou colocando na pasta libs, mas não estou usando nenhuma ferramenta que gerencia dependências. Quando eu tento fazer o build da aplicação que dá esse erro. E sim, é uma aplicação web.

Comment: A minha suposição é esse jar não esteja indo para o classpath da aplicação web. Este código roda em um módulo web ou ejb? Se for no web, está fazendo deploy de um `.war` com o jar na pasta `WEB-INF/libs`, consegue ver isso tanto no projeto quanto no arquivo .war)?

Comment: Ah, me expressei mal, na verdade é só uma aplicação desktop que usa web. É um exemplo bem simples, na verdade.

Comment: Está executando direto pela IDE? Configurou o classpath do projeto pra incluir os jars?

Comment: Isso, direto da IDE. Configurei sim. Como eu disse, inclui todos que ele solicitava. ://

Comment: Felipe, desculpe a demora mas me enrolei aqui. Você importou versão 4.0.6 do smack, chegou a ver se tinha o jar das "extensions" no zip? Olhei o repositório e realmente essa classe esta no projeto "smack-extensions". A minha sugestão seria clonar o repositório, mas pegar apenas o projeto das extensions ou pegar o fonte e criar um projeto "irmão" e fazer a dependência entre eles e executar pra ver.

Comment: @Wakim, era exatamente isso, não tinha percebido que não tinha importado a extensios, pode adicionar como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe `org.jivesoftware.smackx.disco.ServiceDiscoveryManager` pertence ao modulo de **extensions** do smack.

Basta incluir o jar do **smack-extensions** junto ao jar do **smack** no seu projeto.